# How to store Json Web Token (JWT) Secret Key in front-end

Tags: javascript, json, jwt

I want to integrate JWT in my web app to improve security while data was transferred between web apps and server. After reading so many articles regarding JWT, everyone mentioned "Secret Key which is stored only in server side". Now, my question is how can i use secret key in JavaScript on the front-end to build JWT to send it to server.

Comment: Generally speaking you don't **create** JWTs in the front-end, as that would require the private key (or secret) to be publicly visible.

Comment: I'm confused. How can I send secure information to server without someone tampering the request?

Comment: That's what HTTPS is for.

Comment: So that means. After installing SSL in my server, no one can view or' tamper the data transferred between web app and server. Right? If that's right, i have one more doubt, There's no need for all this encryptions and JWT, can i send data simply encrypting to my REST API?

Comment: You don't need JWTs to securely send information from client to server.  JWTs are typically used for *identification* purposes (or rather, they're a token that asserts that you've already established the client's identity).

Comment: Thanks! Now i understand, JWT is the token (That's what I misunderstood - i thought it's a way to send JSON data). So once JWT is created from server side(using login credentials) the same JWT should be sent back and forth and server checks token before processing the request.

Comment: That's correct @DeebashD